# how to compile python py file using IronPython in c# dynamically

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I am calling and executing python(.py) files from C# but before that I would like to validate file either it is valid python file or any syntax/code errors.

How can I compile python code file dynamically before executing file?

Below is my code

```
      using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
      using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
      using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
      using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
      using Newtonsoft.Json;
       using IronPython.Hosting;//for DLHE             



          var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
          var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        try
            {              
           var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", Encoding.UTF8, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.File);
            var compiledCode = scriptSource.Compile();
            compiledCode.Execute(scope);
            //engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", scope);

            // get function and dynamically invoke
            var calcAdd = scope.GetVariable("CalcAdd");
            result = calcAdd(34, 8); // returns 42 (Int32)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionOperations ops = engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>();
            Console.WriteLine(ops.FormatException(ex));
        }
        return result;
```

Comment: I assume you mean in IronPython?

Comment: The way you detect syntax errors is by running the code and catching any exceptions.  There's no way to detect coding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to compile the code before executing. that is the one way I found. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check the IronPython code for errors:

```
public static void CheckErrors()
{
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

    var fileName = "myscript.py";
    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(File.ReadAllText(fileName), fileName, SourceCodeKind.File);

    var sourceUnit = HostingHelpers.GetSourceUnit(source);

    var result = new Result();
    var context = new CompilerContext(sourceUnit, new PythonCompilerOptions(), result);
    var parser = Parser.CreateParser(context, new PythonOptions());
    parser.ParseFile(false);

    // Use the collected diagnostics from the result object here.
}

public class Result : ErrorSink
{
    public override void Add(SourceUnit source, string message, SourceSpan span, int errorCode, Severity severity)
    {
        Add(message, source.Path, null, null, span, errorCode, severity);
    }

    public override void Add(string message, string path, string code, string line, SourceSpan span, int errorCode, Severity severity)
    {
        if (severity == Severity.Ignore)
            return;

        // Collect diagnostics here.
    }
}
```

We used this code to check errors in IronPython scripts for our AlterNET Studio product. Here is how it looks:

[image: AlterNET Studio IronPython script errors]